# Using Dropdown List for options for Search function in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I did work on a Search function where the user can type the item they want to search on a textbox, then hit a button to search.
the Search function is already working but for one option only (ContractNo), now I like to add a Dropdown list to add more options for the users to search (add: EmpID, TrainingCode etc)

> here is the code for the aspx: (yes i only just included the codes that I think is necessary)

```
 <div id="contentarea">
            <p> Search Employee ID, Training Code, Contract Number<br/>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Contract Number</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Training Code</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Employee ID</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:TextBox ID="searchText" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="146px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="ButtonClear_Click" />
            </p>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="TrainingCode" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                   </a>
                        </Itemtemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContractNo" SortExpression="ContractNo">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelContractNo" Text='<% #HighlightText(Eval("ContractNo").ToString()) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TrainingCode" SortExpression="TrainingCode">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelTrainingCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TrainingCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmpID" SortExpression="EmpID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelEmpID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContractDate" SortExpression="ContractDate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelContractDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContractDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContractDuration" SortExpression="ContractDuration">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelContractDuration" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContractDuration") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceStart" SortExpression="ServiceStart">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelServiceStart" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceStart") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContractValue" SortExpression="ContractValue">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelContractValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContractValue") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Served" SortExpression="Served">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelServed" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Served") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbx %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT] WHERE [TrainingCode] = @TrainingCode" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT] ([ContractNo], [TrainingCode], [EmpID], [ContractDate], [ContractDuration], [ServiceStart], [ContractValue], [Served]) VALUES (@ContractNo, @TrainingCode, @EmpID, @ContractDate, @ContractDuration, @ServiceStart, @ContractValue, @Served)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT] SET [ContractNo] = @ContractNo, [EmpID] = @EmpID, [ContractDate] = @ContractDate, [ContractDuration] = @ContractDuration, [ServiceStart] = @ServiceStart, [ContractValue] = @ContractValue, [Served] = @Served WHERE [TrainingCode] = @TrainingCode" FilterExpression="ContractNo '%{0}%'">

                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="ContractNo" ControlID="searchText" PropertyName="Text"/>
                </FilterParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

> and the FULL C# backend code:

```
private string SearchString = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

public string HighlightText(string InputText)
{
    string Search_str = searchText.Text;
    Regex RegExp = new Regex(Search_str.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return RegExp.Replace(InputText, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeywords));
}

public string ReplaceKeywords(Match m) //this is just to highlight the item searched
{
    return ("<span class=highlight>" + m.Value + "</span>");
}


protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchString = searchText.Text;
}

protected void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchText.Text = "";
    SearchString = "";
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Now im thinking to add an if statement maybe? on the FilterParameters? like

```
<% if (DropDownList1.text == "EmpID"){}
```

but Im not sure.. Can you suggest other methods please?? Let me know if you might need other codes from the program. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you clarify the existing problem, what do you want to achieve? and put the code of the gridview from the beginning til the end, where is the query of the search?

Comment: @amal50 the question was edited as requested and the full code of aspx is added. I just want help in building the code for the dropdown list. In which in the dropdownlist options, for example: they chose EmpID, then the user will type an EmpID example: 20134, then click search button , then the results will be displayed at the gridview. Im thinking where to put the codde, on the aspx or the C#. any suggestions? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use generic options. Use DropDown  to list all types (EmpID, TrainingCode). On the basis of type selection use Switch to filter by entered text in TextBox.

SearchString = searchText.Text;
Switch(types)
{
        case EmpID:
        DoOperation();
        break;
        case TrainingCode:
        DoOperation();
        break;
}

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i'll try to think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , here the solution, it's working ok in my computer, I hope this is what you want to achieve. I put some comments in the code, read them

in aspx page , put this code

```
<div id="contentarea">
        <p> Search Employee ID, Training Code, Contract Number<br/>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="ContractNo">Contract Number</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="TrainingCode">Training Code</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="EmpID">Employee ID</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:TextBox ID="searchText" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="146px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="ButtonClear_Click" />
        </p>            

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

and this is the C# code in aspx.cs

```
    private string SearchString = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public string HighlightText(string InputText)
    {
        string Search_str = searchText.Text;
        Regex RegExp = new Regex(Search_str.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return RegExp.Replace(InputText, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeywords));
    }

    public string ReplaceKeywords(Match m) //this is just to highlight the item searched
    {
        return ("<span class=highlight>" + m.Value + "</span>");
    }

    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        // Read connection string from web.config file , Important, change the 
        //ConnectionStrings name here (testConnectionString)
        // and replace it with your connection name , you can find it in web.config file
        // in <connectionStrings> tag , you find it after this tag <add name="

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                con.Open();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SearchString = searchText.Text;
            string columnName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM [SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT] WHERE " + columnName + "= '" + SearchString + "'";


        //bind the SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT table data into GridView1

        DataTable dt = this.GetData(searchSQL);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchText.Text = "";
        SearchString = "";
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```